# How can I get the value of an attribute inside an iframe from parent in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe

How can I pass attribute value from iframe to parent?

I.e. iframe (frame1) has `<a id="a1" href="http://www.infinitybusiness.net">`. How can I get value of `href` in my parent page?

Comment: Is the `<iframe>` on a separate domain, or the same?

Comment: @MrOhad: Why did you add the ‘cross-domain’ tag? The OP doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: because the answers include solution to that case as well :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a great tutorial that talks exactly about that:
http://www.roseindia.net/java/pass-value-example/pass-value-from-iframe-parent.shtml

you can use it only if the two pages are served from the same domain.
There are many solution for cross-domain scripting as well..you can read more here:
http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Answer (score 9):

```
var fra = document.getElementById('frameId');
// following will work on same domain (or subdomain with document.domain set) only
var fraContent = fra.contentDocument || fra.contentWindow.document;
myLinkHref = fraContent.getElementById('myLinkId').href;
```

If this is cross-domain, then you will need to have access to add script to the child frame. If not, it can't be done without a server-side proxy.

Answer (score 1):

it is easy:

- you should use %26 instead of & to send to iframe

**for instance**:

**Link** : `2.asp?ppp=/Payam.asp?sid=1%26PID=1&sa=12313` 
**in Code** : when i `requset.queryString("ppp")` in the parent it shows:
`/Payam.asp?sid=1&PID=1`

you can use this as source of your iframe , it has two parameter

```
<IFRAME name="My"  src='<%=ppp %>'></IFRAME>
```