# pass parameters between iframed pages asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one .aspx page containing three iframes.

First one has menu and second frame is going to open page which is selected from menu.

That off course ok is working fine.

The third page should get parameters from second page passes.

please let me know how to pass parameters between iframed pages.

Comment: Google says: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689145/pass-jquery-variables-between-iframe-and-parent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381920/how-can-i-pass-attribute-value-from-iframe-to-parent-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

That is probably a wrong a approach. Try using masterpages for menus.
If you really have to do it that way, then store parameters in session and either ask the user to refresh the page manually or use AJAX to pull from the server for changes (you can also push from the server side: [asp.net http server push to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471780/asp-net-http-server-push-to-client)).
However, using a [master page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333650/Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-Master-Pages-in-ASP-NET) would probably be the best way to do this.