# does localStorage either or sessionStorage persist in open tab if data stored comes from within an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, local-storage, session-storage

If I load a iFrame into a child element of a tab the user is in, for use by the user as a means of selecting something from an external location, and I were to store that data from the selection using local or session storage methods would I be able to access that data once I close out the iFrame to continue on? Or even at all for that matter?

If not, is there still not a clean method of communicating child window to parent?

Comment: You can only do this (normally) if the iframe is within the same domain as the page needing access to some data within it. This may clarify your situation http://stackoverflow.com/a/3381926/4619012

Comment: the primary part of the domain is the same however, this is a sub domain of the domain. So that brings me to why I originally asked, I should have mentioned that in the original context.

Comment: If both are in the same domain, then you can pass the selected data to the parent window/tab, or use ajax to send the data to the server, or save the data to local storage (accessible because the iframe content location is in the same domain as the parent). Have you tried something that doesn't work, or are you just asking if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a basic example of using localStorage between a parent window and an iFrame.

To demo, enter a value into the main page's textbox and click 'Set Data'. This will set the value in localStorage.
Click 'Read Data' to output the value to the div.

Then enter another value in the iFrame's textbox, and click 'Set Data'.

Finally, click on 'Read Data' again and you will see the value set from the iFrame displayed in the main page's div.

main.html:

```
     <div id="divOne">
        <label>Enter a Value: </label><input id="txtOne" />
        <input type="button" id="btnOne" value="Set Data" onclick="btn1Click(this);" />
        <input type="button" id="btnTwo" value="Read Data" onclick="btn2Click(this);" />
    </div>
    <div id="divTwo"></div>
    <iframe id="ifOne" src="iframe.html"></iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var div2 = document.getElementById('divTwo');
        var btn1 = document.getElementById('btnOne');
        var btn2 = document.getElementById('btnTwo');
        var input1 = document.getElementById('txtOne');

        function btn1Click(e)
        {
            localStorage.dataItem = input1.value;
        }

        function btn2Click(e) {
            div2.innerHTML = localStorage.dataItem;
        }
    </script>
```

iframe.html:

```
    <div>
        <label>Enter a different Value: </label><input id="txtOne" />
        <input type="button" id="btnOne" value="Set Data" onclick="btn1Click(this);" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var btn1 = document.getElementById('btnOne');
        var input1 = document.getElementById('txtOne');

        function btn1Click(e)
        {
            localStorage.dataItem = input1.value;
        }
    </script>
```