# Get values from a href iframe in tables

Tags: javascript

I have on my web iframe with a lot of data values.

Tables have not any id, only classes. All values is in a href in td with class.

Please how to get values from a href in td and at the same time make them separate ?

I want to separate dvalue from each tr.

Each 2 row is in your own table. Thank you very much .

[image: value image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass attribute value from iframe to parent in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381920/how-can-i-pass-attribute-value-from-iframe-to-parent-in-javascript)

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to separate dvalue from each tr.`? And where do `iframe`s come into this issue? There isn't one in your screenshot. Is the iframe on the same domain?

Comment: To understand:

I have approximately 100 tables in iframe. Each table contains two rows and 12 columns. In 11 columns the values are entered in the ahref reference.

I need to use the formula where the variable will be the highest value of the first line and the second variable the highest value of the second row.

And for each two rows (2 rows = 1 table) in particular.

Where the iframe is not mine but someone else.

Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, you are my hero.
I've been trying to change the script for hours but without success. Arrays are not my strong side.

Is it possible to display, in addition to the largest numbers, a new column resulting from the formula?

And at the same time, do not display the largest numbers than the hyperlink but in the input type text and each with its own name? (What would be great for further processing.)

I just need a table where when I click on the radio button (in every two rows 1 button), it automatically throws my result into my php calculator, which has input in input type text. ([a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4nEy.png))

formula:

- the largest number 1 = tln1
- the largest number 2 = tln2

((((tln1 / (tln1 + tln2)) * tln2) + ((tln2 / (tln2 + tln1)) * tln1)) / 2) = number with 3 decimal places

Is anything like that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You've not actually posted any of your own code yet. So update your existing or create a new question with what you have tried thus far, and where you're specifcally stuck.

Comment: Thank you so far, I'm trying to implement what you gave me. However, I have a smaller prick. When I try it on a classic table, everything works great. However, if I implement the script on a page with iframe tables, I do not see any output.
Do you know how to advise me? http://domnakluc.hazmedia.sk/atrakcia.php

Comment: That’s because you need to modify the selector to access the content within the iframe document, not the window document.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, but when I change selector on my ID iframe, no change...
Original: const find = (selector, context = document) => [].slice.call(context.querySelectorAll(selector));

Change: const find = (#Frame2, context = document) => [].slice.call(context.querySelectorAll(#Frame2));

Comment: I’m guessing based on your latest comment that you don’t actually know much about JavaScript at all? You’re trying to modify the find function definition, whereas you should be changing the function parameters passed when it’s called. Perhaps you need to find a qualified developer to help you finish your project.

Comment: Also I've looked at the page you posted, and you're unable to access the iframe content due to CORS restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, does it mean that it is useless to test any script?

Comment: You might be able to write a script to crawl the page content, but I would think most decent bookmakers will protected against that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: will not it work even if the script will run after a full page load? In that case, it will drag values from html and not from iframe. I'm wrong?

Comment: I don't see how. But if you think it will work, try it.